# How to put foreach in array

Tags: php, arrays, json, database, foreach

I have this

```php
$homedata = $user->getbanks();

foreach ($homedata as $data)

echo json_encode(array("replies" => array(array("message" =>    $data->bankname))));
```

I have this put the result am getting is only one array from the list. I want to get all.

Comment: What does `return` do here?

Comment: You changed the Question! Please mention what is your possible output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you need the banknames in an array `replies` within a key `message`. For that the below code will do the job. But you can optimize the query for better performance.

```php
$homedata = $user->getbanks();

$banks['replies'] = [];
foreach ($homedata as $data) {
    $banks['replies'][]['message'] = $data->bankname;
}

print_r(json_encode($banks)); exit;
```

Further, you were only getting the first content because you are overriding the previous content when you iterate using foreach.

Comment: I am able to convert this

 $homedata = $user->getbanks();
                                           
                                                                    
        foreach ($homedata as $message)
        
        
$name[] = $message->bankname;

$names = json_encode($name);

    echo json_encode(array("replies" => array(
        
        
                               array("message" =>    $names  ),
                             
                           
                            
                )));

   
}

Comment: but is including " "

Comment: I am not printing it. this is the sample...is an api


    echo json_encode(array("replies" => array(
        
                               array("message" =>  $name),
                                                           
                           
                            
                )));

   
}

Comment: `echo` is printing. Can you please mention the output you need? I just put the `print_r()` statement to print it into the Screen and can verify the result.

Comment: What you mean by IT DIDN'T WORK. Please explain what you want to achieve. If you can please update the question with sample data that you are looking for. I can't understand what you mean by `but is including ""`.

Comment: What changes you want from my answer?

Comment: look at the updated question. That one I updated works just that it gives only one array if you can restructure it for me so it pulls all the contents

Comment: Please understand when you loop through each element of `$homedata` using `foreach` you are echoing the current iterated element. Thus you will get the same structure with different data until the end of `$homedata` is reached. If you want to get all the data in the same structure, then save it in a variable and print them later (as shown in the answer).

Comment: `[{"message":"Providus Bank Limited"},{"message":"SunTrust Bank Nigeria Limited"},{"message":"Globus Bank Limited"},{"message":"Wema Bank Plc"},{"message":"Unity Bank Plc"},{"message":"Titan Trust Bank Limited"},{"message":"Sterling Bank Plc"},{"message":"Standard Chartered"},{"message":"Stanbic IBTC Bank Plc"},{"message":"Polaris Bank Limited"},{"message":"Keystone Bank Limited"},{"message":"Heritage Banking Company Limited"},{"message":"Ecobank Nigeria Plc"},{"message":"Citibank Nigeria Limited"},{"message":"United Bank for Africa Plc"}]` this is the result... no reply in it

Comment: This is the expected result `{"replies":[{"message":"good"},{"message":"bad"}]}`

Comment: That's why I have asked you the end result so many times. ha ha.. 
Please understand the concepts and work around it, that will make you understand the working. All the best